# jQuery find content and highlight element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am getting this error "Please enter your email address." from server side validation after form is submit. I am checkig if this error display "Please enter your email address." i am applying CSS border to spacific input element for highlighting.

My jQuery Code:

```
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(".register_btn").click(function(){
    if(jQuery( ".left_reset_bar li:contains('Please enter your email address.')" )){
        jQuery('.left_reset_bar #jform_email').addClass('highlightError');
    }
});
```

But code is not working :(

Any ideas or suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
jQuery.noConflict();
if(jQuery( ".left_reset_bar li:contains('Please enter your email address.')" )){
    jQuery('.left_reset_bar #jform_email').addClass('highlightError');
}
```

You don't need to bind click handler, because the function is triggered before form submit. Meaning there wasn't `li` element with *"Please enter your email address."* text in DOM, when the function trigger.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned that you are getting the error "Please enter your email address." from server side validation after form is submit. But below mentioned code will check for string "Please enter your email address." on click of register button.i.e., before passing request to server (before form submit).

```
jQuery(".register_btn").click(function(){
    if(jQuery( ".left_reset_bar li:contains('Please enter your email address.')" )){
        jQuery('.left_reset_bar #jform_email').addClass('highlightError');
    }
});
```

You should handle this after getting response from server.

Answer (score 0):

Click event for the register button will fire prior to your server side event. Hence the Class will not be added to your required tag. Inorder to execute as per your requirement move your logic to some function as below and then call your javascript function from the code behind as below mentioned code and then check

```
function HighlightMessage()
{
//Your logic to add Class
}
```

Code to call your javascript function from the code behind

this.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), "HighlightMessage();", true);

Add the above line in your server side click event handler of your register button i.e below the line where you set your message "Please enter your email address.".

Answer (score 0):

[image]    
    $(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery(".register_btn").click(function(){alert("dsd");
         if(jQuery( ".left_reset_bar li:contains('Please enter your email address.')" ))
            {
                jQuery( ".left_reset_bar li:contains('Please enter your email address.')" ).addClass('highlightError');
            }
        });
    });

Comment: class is not adding :(

Comment: yes it's add a class on li i test it,please check attached image

Comment: yes now class added but after page reload it gone. i want also after page reload.

Comment: @manan: You have to call your javascript code to add class after your server side event is fired. Please check my above post for that and follow that, you will find your solution. Hope you understand what i mean to say.

Comment: @PrashantKankhara okay let me try.